# HTML form, prevent refresh after clicking submit

Tags: php, html, forms

I need to prevent refreshing the page after clicking on submit button. I've tried methods like

```
$("#prospects_form").submit(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
```

and "onsubmit="return false" or "type=button"....but the problem is, even though all of these methods work, it seems that my php script doesn't get executed

this is my form

```
<form method="POST" action="storeImage.php">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6" id="the_cam">
                        <div id="my_camera"></div>

                        <div id="start_webcam">
                            <input style="font-size:13px" type=button class="btn-get-started" value="Start webcam" onClick="start_webcam()">
                        </div>
                        <br />

                        <div id="take_snapshot" style="visibility: hidden;">
                            <input class="btn-get-started" type=button value="Take Snapshot" onClick="take_snapshot()">
                        </div>
                        <input type="hidden" name="image" class="image-tag">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div id="results" style="text-align: center;"></div>

                        <br />
                        <div id="submit" style="visibility: hidden; margin-top:60px;">
                            <button class="btn-get-started" onclick="submit_image()">Submit</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Oh and that "submit_image" function is irrelevant..might not as well be there

Comment: where is your `#prospects_form` id in `<form>` Tag?

Comment: So you want to submit the data without reloading the whole page? In that case you need to use AJAX.

Comment: and you are using 2 things `onclick="submit_image()"` and `action="storeImage.php"` in your <form>

Comment: Thank you guys... solved by sending AJAX request